# in-place vs allocating API

Tags: c, api

I need to create a library in C and I am wondering how to manage objects: returning allocated (ex: fopen, opendir) or in-place initialization (ex: GNU hcreate_r).

I understand that it is mostly [a question of taste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431849), and I'm inclined to choose the allocating API because of the convenience when doing lazy initialization (by testing if the object pointer is NULL).

However, after reading [Ulrich's paper (PDF)](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf), I'm wondering if this design will cause locality of reference problems, especially if I compose objects from others:

```
struct opaque_composite {
    struct objectx *member1;
    struct objecty *member2;
    struct objectz *member2;
    /* ... */
};
```

Allocation of such an object will make a cascade of other sub-allocations. Is this a problem in practice? And are there other issues that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to consider is whether the type of the object the function constructs is *opaque*. An opaque type is only forward-declared in the header file and the only thing you can do with it is having a pointer to it and passing that pointer to separately compiled API functions. `FILE` in the standard library is such an opaque type. For an opaque type, you have no option but have to provide an allocation and a deallocation function as the user has no other way to obtain a reference to an object of that type.

If the type is not opaque – that is, the definition of the `struct` is in the header file – it is more versatile to have a function that does only *initialization* – and, if required, another that does finalization – but no allocation and deallocation. The reason is that with this interface, the *user* can decide whether to put the objects on the stack…

```
struct widget w;
widget_init(&w, 42, "lorem ipsum");
// use widget…
widget_fini(&w);
```

…or on the heap.

```
struct widget * wp = malloc(sizeof(struct widget));
if (wp == NULL)
  exit(1);  // or do whatever
widget_init(wp, 42, "lorem ipsum");
// use widget…
widget_fini(wp);
free(wp);
```

If you think that this is too much typing, you – or your users themselves – can easily provide convenience functions.

```
inline struct widget *
new_widget(const int n, const char *const s)
{
  struct widget wp = malloc(sizeof(struct widget));
  if (wp != NULL)
    widget_init(wp, n, s);
  return wp;
}

inline void
del_widget(struct widget * wp)
{
  widget_fini(wp);
  free(wp);
}
```

Going the other way round is not possible.

Interfaces should always provide the essential building blocks to compose higher-level abstractions but not make legitimate uses impossible by being overly restrictive.

Of course, this leaves us with the question when to make a type opaque. A good rule of thumb – that I have first seen in the [coding standards](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) for the *Linux* kernel – might be to make types opaque only if there are no data members your users could meaningfully access. I think this rule should be refined a little to take into account that non-opaque types allow for “member” functions to be provided as `inline` versions in the header files which might be desirable from a performance point of view. On the other hand, opaque types provide better encapsulation (especially since C has no way to restrict access to a `struct`'s members). I would also lean towards an opaque type more easily if making it not opaque would force me to `#include` headers into the header file of my library because they provide definitions of the types used as members in my type. (I'm okay with `#include`ing `<stdint.h>` for `uint32_t`. I'm a little less easy about `#include`ing a large header such as `<unistd.h>` and I'd certainly try to avoid having to `#include` a header from a third-party library such as `<curses.h>`.)

Answer (score 0):

IMO the "cascade of sub-allocations" is not a problem if you keep the object opaque so you can keep it in a consistent state.  The creation and destruction routines will have some added complexity dealing with an allocation failure part way through creation, but nothing too onerous.

Besides the option to have a static/stack-allocated copy *(which I'm generally not fond of anyway)*, in my mind, the main advantage of a scheme like:

```
x = initThang(thangPtr);
```

is the ease of returning a variety of more specific error codes.