# problem extracting the length of an array of characters from a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _Text { 
  char *str; 
  int length; 
  int counter; 
  } *Text;

Text text(char *txtStr){  
  Text txt= malloc(sizeof(*txt));
  txt->str=txtStr; 
  txt->counter=1;
  txt->length=sizeof(*txtStr);
  return txt;
}

int main(void) {
  
  Text txt= text("hello");

  return 0;
}
```

I need to extract the array length however pointer only returns the size of the first element, how can I determine the length of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string in C is a series of characters terminated by a NUL (aka `'\0'`), so you could count how many characters there are like

```
char *pos = txtStr;
txt->length = 0;
while(*pos != '\0')
  {
  txt->length++;
  pos++;
  }
```

or because life is too long to keep writing code that does things like that, there is a standard function that does all the hard work for you called `strlen`

```
txt->length = strlen(txtStr);
```

Also you want to make a copy of `txtStr` as its contents may pass out of scope before your newly created `Text` does...

Comment: yep that did the trick, thanks for the help man, however you need to sum positions to the pointer too, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @CorbelJhonshon oops, you're right - I forgot to increment `pos`!

Answer (score 1):

Use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add something:
After using malloc, you should free that memory when it is not needed anymore.
I guess it is just an example code, but it is best to get used to writing that way.
And returning an allocated memory could be problematic if not dealt with properly (Good answer for it here: [Is it bad manners to return a heap allocated pointer from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431698/is-it-bad-manners-to-return-a-heap-allocated-pointer-from-a-function))

Again, I know your question was purely an example, but it is best to be aware. :)

Comment: yeah, I free the memorie on the original program, but thanks for the advise anyway

Comment: FYI, this is probably better suited as a comment because it is not actually an answer to the OPs question.